# Row rank and column rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is very basic and fundamental theorem in linear algebra or matrix theory that the row rank and column rank of a matrix are same. Several people gave interesting elementary proofs of it. At the first time, it seems not so straight-forward to prove this theorem.

I initially thought in the following way: let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. By elementary row operations, row rank of $A$ doesn't change, and the matrix can be reduced to a row-echelon form. However, there are some subtle points moving in this direction: it doesn't seem obvious/easy to show that

1) row operations do not change column rank of $A$

2) for a matrix in reduced row-echelon form, its row rank and column rank are same.

So, since these two statements I couldn't prove in some natural arguments, I went in the following way:

Think of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as vector space of column vectors over $\mathbb{R}$ of dimension $n$ (i.e. space of $n\times 1$ matrices). Then $A$ can be considered as a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. In this setup, the row rank of $A$ is simply the dimension of image space of map $A$. Then the question arises is

> **Q.** Can we show that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n/\ker A$ is the column rank of $A$?

---

My aim in the question is not to understand some well-known proof of the theorem under consideration; but I want to see the obstacles and how to remove them if we proceed in some natural arguments, as stated above.

Comment: You can use the fact that $\mathrm{Ker}\left( A\right) =\mathrm{Im}\left( A^{T}\right) ^{\bot }$.

Comment: Orthogonal complement w.r.t. what? which inner product?

Comment: The standard inner product.

Comment: A linear map is a group [homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) between vector spaces (abelian groups under addition). Your result follows immediately from the [fundamental theorem on homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_on_homomorphisms) (see the special case for the kernel [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#First_isomorphism_theorem)) as ${\mathbb R}^n/\ker A$ and $\operatorname{im}A$ are isomorphic.

Comment: May I ask to clarify some uncertainties. Do you mean that "1) row operations *does not* change the column rank of $A$" and "the *column* rank of $A$ is simply the dimension of the image space"?

Comment: @Nyfiken: Thanks very much for pointing out the confusing statement; I am sorry for it. I have edited it.

Comment: Are you sure that the row rank (not the column rank) is the dimension of your image space?

Comment: One approach is to show that row rank equals the determinant rank and the property that determinant of a matrix remains invariant when transposing it. Anyway the result you seek to prove is neither obvious nor easy to prove so you are bound to get challenges while proving it.